# Aspnet compiler in-place compilation cannot load assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnet-compiler

I would like to do an in-place compilation of my website. When I start aspnet compiler it gives me an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibraryDll, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2ac5f5f5484c304c' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I set physical path to the directory where I unpacked my wsp, the missing dll is clearly there. I set the virtual path to / so far and tried many more options like ".", ./, temp. However, I stopped believing that the virtual paht is the key to the solution.

What should I do so that the compiler sees my ddls? Is the only possibility to place them in GAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to create folder named "bin" in the physical path folder and place all dlls there.